# How to destroy bootstrap modal scope onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Onclick bootstarp modal is opening again and again.. on top of another div.

What I am trying to do is - when user click on button show the pop up.. onclick or again different popup close the popup and open again..

I am trying to destroy the $modal.

I am using angular bootstrap.

My unsaved-changes.html HTML -

```
<div class="modal-header">
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <h4 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> {{'unsavedChanges' | translate}}</h4>
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <span class="span4" ng-if="dashboardName!=='empty'">
            {{changes}}
        </span>    
      <div class="editor-row" ng-if="dashboardName==='empty'">
        <form name="saveForm" ng-submit="save();dismiss();" novalidate>
         <input class='input-medium' placeholder="empty" ng-model="$parent.$parent.unsavedtitle"  type="text" ng-required="true" style="width:300px"/>
          <button class="btn  pull-right" ng-click="ignore();dismiss();">{{'ignore'| translate}}</button>
          <button class="btn  pull-right" ng-disabled="saveForm.$error.required" ng-if="($parent.$parent.unsavedtitle| lowercase)!=='empty'">{{'save'| translate}}</button>
          <button class="btn  pull-right" ng-disabled="true" ng-if="($parent.$parent.unsavedtitle| lowercase)==='empty'">{{'ignore' | translate}}</button>
        </form>
      </div>   
  <div class="modal-body" ng-if="dashboardName!=='empty'">
    <button type="button" class="btn span2" ng-click="save();dismiss();">{{'save' | translate}}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn span2" ng-click="ignore();dismiss();">{{'ignore' | translate}}</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

My service -

```
this.init = function() {
      self.check_unsaved_changes = config.unsaved_changes_warning;
      $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next) {
        if ((self.originalPath === $location.path()) || !self.check_unsaved_changes) {
          return;
        }
        if (self.has_unsaved_changes()) {
          event.preventDefault();
          self.next = next;
          $rootScope.unsavedtitle="";
          $timeout(self.open_modal);
        }
      });
    };

    this.checkForUnsavedChanges = function(checkUnsavedChanges) {
      self.check_unsaved_changes = checkUnsavedChanges;
    };

    this.open_modal = function() {
      var confirmModal = $modal({
        template: 'app/partials/unsaved-changes.html',
        persist: true,
        show: false,
        scope: modalScope,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
      });

      $q.when(confirmModal).then(function(modalEl) {
        modalEl.modal('show');
      });
    };
```

Comment: Please provide sufficient code to reproduce the issue. Currently your code also refers to local files like `app/partials/unsaved-changes.html`. 
Provide a JSFiddle demo (https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can help.

Comment: I shared my html code.. unsaved-changes.html file code is already available.. please check..